# Differentiability of solution to ODE

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider the problem 
$$\frac{d X(t,x)}{dt} = f(t, X(t,x))$$
$$X(0,x) = x$$
where $f:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $f$ is Holder continuous or Lipschitz continuous. How can I prove and where can I find a reference for the fact that $X$ is differentiable and 
$$\nabla X$$ is the solution to 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \nabla X(t,x) = \nabla f(t,X(t,x)) \nabla X(t,x)?$$
 Do we need to assume that $f$ is differentiable of does the Lipschitz continuity suffice?
Also, does the formula 
$$\nabla X = e^{\int_0^T\nabla f}$$
hold if at least $f \in L^1((0,T),W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for example? If not, why?

Comment: Your last statement is in general false, though it is a widely-held misconception, see [my answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/296016#296016).

Comment: @user539887 Thanks. Then in this case what is the explicit form of the solution to the second ODE in the question? Shouldn't the formula hold if $f \in L^1((0,T),W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ for example?

Comment: You need commutativity of all the matrices for the exponential formula. If that is not given, then there is something called a time-ordered exponential. || To write down the derivative of $f$ as you did, you need some kind of differentiability of $f$ in the assumptions.

Comment: @LutzL What do you mean by commutativity of the matrices? Which matrices?

Comment: I mean the Jacobian matrices $∇f\in\Bbb R^{n×n}$ that you put in the integral. In general $X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$ can not be solved via the exponential of the integral $\exp(\int A(t)dt)$ as that requires that all matrices $A(t)$ commute with each other.

Comment: For a counterexample, take $x'=A(t)x$ with $A(t) = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&2t\\ 0&2 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$.

Comment: @user539887 What assumptions give us such commutativity?

Comment: @LutzL What assumptions give us such commutativity?

Comment: Commutativity is an assumption by itself: $A(t)A(s)=A(s)A(t)$ for all $s,t\in(0,T)$. Indeed, it can be relaxed: there is $t_0\in(0,T)$ such that $A(s)(\int\limits_{t_0}^t A(\tau)\,d\tau)=(\int\limits_{t_0}^t A(\tau)\,d\tau)A(s)$ for all $s,t\in(0,T)$. Perhaps you ask what are assumptions on $f$ that guarantee the commutativity of the Jacobian matrices? To such a question I do not know an answer, I am afraid.